# import matplotlib fails with "'module' object not callable" error

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module

This question may appear similar to previously asked questions, but it is not.
I have a Python script with a single line:

`import matplotlib`

This fails with the error:

'module' object is not callable

random.py - print a random integer between 1 and 100

(followed by 3 more lines of usage of random.py)

If I start python from the command line, then type

> import matplotlib

That works. I can instantiate classes from the module, plot figures and so on.

I am completely lost as to what is going on. Any clue appreciated.

Python version `2.6.6` on `64 bit x86 Linux machine`.

Comment: The question does not allow to judge on the origin of the error. Please provide a [mcve] of the issue and the full error traceback (indicating in which line of the code the error occurs).

Comment: There is no error traceback. The Python script has one line. That line is 'import matplotlib'. I call it from command line as 'python script.py'. I see the output as described in the original question. OTOH if I start the Python CLI, and type 'import matplotlib' at the '>>>' prompt, things work fine.

Comment: If the script.py contains one single line, where does *"random.py - print a random integer between 1 and 100
(followed by 3 more lines of usage of random.py)"*  come from? If there is an error, there is **always** an error traceback, it will consist of at least 3 lines shown below your command. You may also post a screenshot if you want.

Comment: I don't know where the 'random.py' lines are coming from. There is no other command in the script, not even another import, except this one line. I type 'python script.py <enter>'. The computer types back 'module' object is not callable' followed by four lines starting with 'random.py' about usage. I have programmed in Python for 11 years and have never seen this and don't know how to debug further. Hence my question. I am not being obtuse, I am just not sure how to proceed. As I said, the import works in a Python CLI.

Comment: Yes, asking that question is perfectly fine. But having that much experience you might know yourself that with the information at hand it is rather difficult to help. At least we now know that the problem does not come from `import matplotlib` at all, but rather from some ghost code being executed. So you need to find out where those "`random.py - print a random...`" lines come from. Will they be present if you run a different script? Will they be present if you restart the Kernel? etc.

Comment: Used 'python -i' option to get traceback. The error is because I have my own random.py which comes in the UNIX path before the 'official' random.py. Thanks all for trying to help.

Comment: See, I did ask for the complete error traceback 7 hours ago. Now that you finally had a look at it, you were even able to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**"Matplotlib is the whole package; matplotlib.pyplot is a module in matplotlib; and pylab is a module that gets installed alongside matplotlib.
Pyplot provides the state-machine interface to the underlying object-oriented plotting library"**

I took this from matplotlib manual website so You might want to take a look at.
https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html

I dont know how you are trying you access your module but mistake is about matplotlib is not a module but its a whole package so you should call a module from inside of it. So you should call your module as one of style shown in the below

import matplotlib.pyplot

from matplotlib import figure or pyplot this part upto your module.

Comment: I was just going to write up an answer and then you posted this. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah you're welcome! :)  and Sorry if I stole the question from you :(

Comment: Actually I do not understand this answer. Why exactly does `import matplotlib` fail here? Mind that `import matplotlib` is perfectly valid code. Even [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) (look at point 4) uses it.

Comment: Yes but as I said earlier " I dont know how you are trying to access your module.", with given information I can just tell this much about this general error sorry. Since We dont have any specific action which leads to an error, He might also wanted to check env variables. Maybe he might imported the matplotlib then trying to call it like matplotlib(variable) and since matplotlib is not callable this error might pop up which has the same solution as i showed. I knew using import matplotlib is perfectly valid code but what you are doing after that might lead to arise an error.

Comment: My original question did state that I have a single line Python script. That line is "import matplotlib".

Comment: So the original post asks why `import matplotlib` fails and your answer is that the poster should not use it but use `import matplotlib.pyplot` instead; although this is not what he actually wants to do? Does not make any sense.

Comment: Seeing the actual cause of the error, this answer makes even less sense.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib is an entire library, so if you are using import matplotlib as plt in your code, it might not work. Use 'import matplotlib.plyplot as plt' instead.